# How can I gift Call of Duty 4 to a friend without linking his account?

Tags: battle.net, humble-bundle, call-of-duty-black-ops-4

I subscribe to the monthly Humble Bundle games package. The big name game this month was Call of Duty Black Ops 4. I'm not really a fan of multi-player shooters, but I have a friend who enjoys them. I'd like to gift my copy of the game to him but the Humble Monthly key's page doesn't have a clear option to gift this game without linking his battle.net account to my Humble Bundle account.

[image: Key's page]

Obviously I'd prefer not to link the accounts and just gift the key like I can do with Steam.  Is it possible to gift him the game without linking his account?

---

After reading the [Redemption Instructions](https://support.humblebundle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010659333-Redeeming-Activision-Blizzard-Keys-through-Direct-Entitlement) link I'm even more confused. On that page they have the following warning/notice in red:

> Please keep in mind that for the gifting option to be available you will need to have your Battle.net account linked to your Humble Bundle account as detailed above.

That seems pretty straight forward even though I don't currently have a Battle.net account, but then this image makes me wonder if I could even gift the game after creating my own Battle.net account:

[image: Gifting example]

Why are they asking to link an account and showing the gift button at the same time if you can only gift a game if you have an account linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No.  You and your friend both need to have linked Battle.net accounts to your respective Humble Bundle accounts.](https://support.humblebundle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010659333-Redeeming-Activision-Blizzard-Keys-through-Direct-Entitlement)

You need to have **your** account linked as per their help page in order to send the gift.

[image]

After you link your [Battle.net](https://us.battle.net/account/creation/en/) account to your Humble Bundle account, an option will appear to email your gift to a friend.

[image]

From there, your friend just needs to go to their email and click the link.

[image]

But after that, your friend will also need to have a Battle.net account linked in order to actually claim the gift.

[image]

Comment: That's incorrect. Some Activision games CAN be gifted without having a b.net account.

Comment: @Xander Some can.  This one can't.  This question is asking about Black Ops 4, not Activision games in general.

Answer (score 1):

Just above the image you linked it clearly states:

> Some Activision / Blizzard games will also be giftable from the Download Page. If so you will see this message on the Download Page.
>
> [image]

In other words, some games can be gifted only through battle.net and you need to link/create an account to gift them, and others don't require a battle.net account to gift them.

Comment: The recipient for Battle.net games needs to also have a Battle.net account linked to their own Humble account.  As I had already answered below.